# Opening mddialog scrolls the page to top

Tags: angularjs

When i use the $mddialog service as below

```
 $mdDialog.show({
         parent: parentEl,
         targetEvent: $event,
         template:
           '<md-dialog aria-label="List dialog">' +
           '  <md-dialog-content>'+
           '    <md-list>'+
           '      <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">'+
           '       <p>Number {{item}}</p>' +
           '      '+
           '    </md-list-item></md-list>'+
           '  </md-dialog-content>' +
           '  <md-dialog-actions>' +
           '    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
           '      Close Dialog' +
           '    </md-button>' +
           '  </md-dialog-actions>' +
           '</md-dialog>',
         locals: {
           items: $scope.items
         },
         controller: DialogController
      });
```

I see that the page scrolls to top and the dialog opens.
I tried setting the position absolute for md-dialog ,but it doesn't work.
Is there any way to set the position of the dialog

Comment: are you using PerfectScrollbar https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar ?

Comment: No, i am using the above code in a directive. And i am using that as below:
<a my-directive>